# how to remove words with "(" in a string in r?

Tags: regex, r, string, replace, gsub

i have the following string:

```
str<-c("hello(world(howr u doin")
```

I want to remove the word "hello(world(howr" from the string. I want my output to be

```
str2<-c("u doin")
```

the error that i get by using

```
gsub("hello(world(howr","", str)
```

is:  invalid expression, reason 'Missing ')''

Please not that i will use this function over a iteration of strings and we cannot say in which position "(" would occur in a string. so, I would request you to provide a global solution. Thank you. 
Also, I would request you to note that, the words that are to be removed in the string may be different at different times. So i would like a regex which tells to ignore the meaning of the special characters in the word that is to be removed.

here is a real world situation

```
library(stringr)
library(NLP)
library(openNLP)
text_sa<-as.String("`$%`$> http://t.co/W9wDz8yhZE @AshramOrg @villan_TKRrength! #WeSupport_`$8`$(`$>`$$`$(_`$8`$`$8`% ")
removalwords<-c("#WeSupport_`$8`$(`$>`$$`$(_`$8`$\002`$8`%", "@AshramOrg")
for(k in 1:length(removalwords)){
text_sa <- gsub(removalwords[k], "", text_sa)
}
```

My expected output is

```
text_sa<-as.String("`$%`$> http://t.co/W9wDz8yhZE @villan_TKRrength!")
```

Comment: I get error copy/pasting the new code `Error: unexpected '>' in "text_sa<-as.String(`$%`$>"`

Comment: @akrun sorry, I forgot to include " in the string. I edited it now. please try again.

Comment: Now, I get the error `Error: could not find function "as.String"`

Comment: @please load the library (stringr)

Comment: @areddy what's your expected output?

Comment: @areddy that function won't exists in string r

Comment: @akrun : please load package "NLP" to get as.String function

Comment: @AvinashRaj : please load package "NLP" to get as.String function

Comment: Thank you both for the concern regarding the issue. It would be of a great help if this issue is resolved

Comment: i don't know how this `"#WeSupport_`$8`$(`$>`$$`$(_`$8`$\002`$8`%"` regex would match `#WeSupport_`$8`$(`$>`$$`$(_`$8`$`$8`%`

Comment: @AvinashRaj that is the main issue. I jus want to know how to supress the literal meaning of special characters in that word.  Anyways, thank you so much for the efforts sir. :)

Comment: @areddy understodd, check my edit........

Comment: I was about to comment, looks like you deleted the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape brackets since brackets are special chars in regex. Since the replacement would occur only one time, you don't need to go for `gsub`. `sub` alone would be sufficient.

```
sub("hello\\(world\\(howr\\s*","", str)
```

or

```
sub("^\\S+\\s*", "", str)
```

**Edit:**

```
x <- "`$%`$> http://t.co/W9wDz8yhZE @AshramOrg @villan_TKRrength! #WeSupport_`$8`$(`$>`$$`$(_`$8`$`$8`% "
remove <- c("#WeSupport_`$8`$(`$>`$$`$(_`$8`$`$8`%", "@AshramOrg")
gsub(paste(gsub("([^\\w\\s])", "\\\\\\1", remove, perl=T),collapse="|"), "", x, perl=T)
[1] "`$%`$> http://t.co/W9wDz8yhZE  @villan_TKRrength!  "
```

Comment: Please not that i will use this function over a iteration of strings and we cannot say in which position "(" would occur in a string. so, I would request you to provide a global solution. Thank you. Also, I would request you to note that, the words that are to be removed in the string may be different at different times. So i would like a regex which tells to ignore the meaning of the special characters in the word that is to be removed.

Comment: @areddy  So please post an example reflecting your **real** situation.

Comment: Thanks .. please give me a minute

Comment: @areddy you may try this `gsub("\\S*[^\\w\\s]\\S*", "", str)` . If it won't works then provide an example.

Comment: I get `''` as the output.

Comment: Hello all, I have provided a real world example now. Please have a look at it. Thank you

Comment: @Pascal :  hello, I included a real world situation. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: hello, I included a real world situation. Please have a look at it.